# How to add a new publication to a blogdown academic themed website

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to add a new publication to the publications section of [my Hugo-Academic website](https://emmanuelteitelbaum.com) in R using the blogdown package. I thought I might try the wrapper function for new content:

`new_content(path, kind = "", open = interactive())`

But the [blogdown documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blogdown/blogdown.pdf) doesn't provide much detail about how to use it. I tried it like this:

`blogdown::new_content(publication/newpublication, kind = "publication", open = interactive())`

And I get the following message:

```
Error in xfun::with_ext(...) : object 'publication' not found
```

What am I missing?